# JSON Extract to dataframe using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a JSON file and the structure of the file is as below

[json file with the structure][1]
I am trying to get all the details into dataframe or tabular form, Tried using denormalize and could not get the actual result.

```
                            {

        "body": [{
                "_id": {
                    "s": 0,
                    "i": "5ea6c8ee24826b48cc560e1c"
                },
                "fdfdsfdsf": "V2_1_0",
                "dsd": "INDIA-",
                "sdsd": "df-as-3e-ds",
                "dsd": 123,
                "dsds": [{
                        "dsd": "s_10",
                        "dsds": [{
                                "dsdsd": "OFFICIAL",
                                "dssd": {
                                    "dsds": {
                                        "sdsd": "IND",
                                        "dsads": 0.0
                                    }
                                },
                                "sadsad": [{
                                        "fdsd": "ABC",
                                        "dds": {
                                            "dsd": "INR",
                                            "dfdsfd": -1825.717444
                                        },
                                        "dsss": [{
                                                "id": "A:B",
                                                "dsdsd": "A.B"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }, {
                                        "name": "dssadsa",
                                        "sadds": {
                                            "sdsads": "INR",
                                            "dsadsad": 180.831415
                                        },
                                        "xcs": "L:M",
                                                "sds": "L.M"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    }
```

Comment: Please don't attach images, but copy the code in the question

Comment: @Joe : i have copied the json

Comment: Show your required output... in image or anything.

Comment: @StackKiddy: i have added the output

Answer (score 0):

This structure is far too nested to put directly into a dataframe. First, you'll need to use the ol' `flatten_json` function. This function isn't in a library (to my knowledge), but [you see it around a lot.](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-objects-in-non-recursive-elegant-python-55f96533103d) Save it somewhere.

```
def flatten_json(nested_json):
    """
        Flatten json object with nested keys into a single level.
        Args:
            nested_json: A nested json object.
        Returns:
            The flattened json object if successful, None otherwise.
    """
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
```

Applying it to your data:

```
import json

with open('deeply_nested.json', r) as f: 
    flattened_json = flatten_json(json.load(f))

df = pd.json_normalize(flattened_json)
df.columns

Index(['body_0__id_s', 'body_0__id_i', 'body_0_schemaVersion',
       'body_0_snapUUID', 'body_0_jobUUID', 'body_0_riskSourceID',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_scenario',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_modelPolicyLabel',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_valuation_pv_unit',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_valuation_pv_value',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_0_name',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_0_value_unit',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_0_value_value',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_0_riskFactors_0_id',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_0_riskFactors_0_underlyingRef',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_1_name',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_1_value_unit',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_1_value_value',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_1_riskFactors',
       'body_0_scenarioSets_0_modelSet_0_measures_1_underlyingRef'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: I have imported module
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize ,

but getting error message as 
AttributeError: module 'pandas.json' has no attribute 'load'

Comment: Sorry, you should import the python lib json: `import json`